# Can we have hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hats

Several Stackexchange meta sites are reporting that there will be an optional event where one could earn "hats" for your gravatar (profile icon) to wear.

See these questions for details:

https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5240/do-we-want-hats

https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/525/do-we-want-hats

https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/do-we-want-to-participate-in-this-years-hat-dash

https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/287/winter-bash-holiday-hats

Should we participate in this fun event?

Comment: Most definitely we should!

Comment: I applaud your initiative! This is the only meta post I've seen that hasn't been put up by the mods. :)

Answer (score 15):

Yes we definitely should have hats!

Comment: I concur! Let's do it!

Comment: I've now signed us up for hats.

Comment: So how do u get the Hats?

Answer (score 5):

Thank you for providing an "I hate hats" option. I really do hate hats :)

Comment: And besides, it's summer! (for me, at least)

Comment: Summer for me too, but that is the season for stupid hats. I particularly like the mayan hat this year - always nice to celebrate that we can't solve the Halting Problem for the planet, again.