# Is GIS SE participating in 2015 Winter Bash Holiday Hats Promotion?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, hats

I came across [this](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2082/poll-should-we-participate-in-the-2015-winter-bash-holiday-hats-promotion?cb=1) post at the Academia SE and I wondered if members at GIS SE would like to participate in the 2015 Winter Bash Holiday Hats Promotion too?

Are we participating in 2015 SE 'winterbash'? if so, should we set up a poll?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Last year's poll was so clearly in favour of Hats (see [Should GIS participate in the 2014 “Winter Bash”?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3829/115)) that I proposed to the other mods that we simply accept the default option which is that we get Hats.

Just for a bit more transparency, the relevant contents of the email to moderators about this year's hats were:

> As moderators in our network, you represent the communities that you
>   watch over. No one knows your sites better than you do. As such, you
>   all get to decide if they will opt in or not.
>
> Here’s what you’ll need to do:
>
> - Discuss this among your teams. If your team is unsure, or you just want to get your community’s opinion first, ask on your meta. If
>     results are mixed, either make an executive decision or ask for
>     assistance from the Community Team.
> - If you want in, you don't need to do anything; that's the default this year, due to overwhelming positive response in previous years.

I figured that if there was a strong hat hating contingent then we would hear about it quickly on Meta.  For the record, I changed my position from being against them previously to pro-hats this year.

Comment: Individuals can still opt out, right?

Comment: @BradHards yes - you'll see "I hate hats" and/or "take off your hats everywhere" buttons in various places which you can click to suppress them.

Comment: Hat's off to everyone choosing to keep hats on!

Comment: "Winter" bash is hemispherist. It's summer south of that imaginary little line...